# How to designate spot instance pricing in a CloudFormation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I'm creating an EMR cluster within a CloudFormation script, and I am successfully able to run it to completion and get the stack to build, but now I'm wondering how to implement spot pricing in the CF template as well.

Here's what I'm working with for the cluster creation:

```
"Resources": {
    "MyCluster": {
        "Type": "AWS::EMR::Cluster",
        "Properties": {
            "Applications": [
                { "Name" : "Hadoop" },
                { "Name" : "SPARK" },
                { "Name" : "Ganglia" }
            ],
            "BootstrapActions" : [...],
            "Instances": {
                "AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups" : [{ "Fn::GetAtt" : ["rAllowJupyter","GroupId"] }],
                "Ec2KeyName" : { "Ref" : "EC2KeyName" },
                "Ec2SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "Subnet" },
                "MasterInstanceGroup": {
                    "InstanceCount": 1,
                    "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }
                },
                "CoreInstanceGroup": {
                    "InstanceCount": { "Ref" : "CoreNodeCount" },
                    "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }
                }
            },
            "Configurations": [...],
            "Name": "MyCluster",
            "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
            "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
            "ReleaseLabel": "emr-4.6.0",
            "LogUri": "s3://path/to/logs/",
            "Tags": [
                { "Key": "Name", "Value": "aqa-spark"},
                { "Key": "Owner",   "Value": { "Ref" : "OwnerTag" }},
                { "Key": "Purpose", "Value": { "Ref" : "PurposeTag" }}
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

Are there parameters that I can use to designate spot-instances within an EMR cluster for my CloudFormation script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `MasterInstanceGroup` (or any other) use spot instances by adding a `Market` and `BidPrice` parameter to the configuration.

For example, to have `r3.large` spot instances for $0.10:

```
"MasterInstanceGroup": {
  "InstanceCount": 1,
  "InstanceType": "r3.large",
  "Market": "SPOT",
  "BidPrice": "0.10"
}
```

Source: [Amazon EMR Cluster JobFlowInstancesConfig InstanceGroupConfig](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-emr-cluster-jobflowinstancesconfig-instancegroupconfig.html) documentation

Comment: thanks! I thought this question would die without an answer. you're the man.